# export a qlikview doc (qvd) as a HTMl or a XML

Tags: qlikview

I have made a Qlikview document (QVD). and a Qlikview report. IS there any way this report/document can be exported into a HTML/XML so that it can be sent as an attachment to another location and utilized for further processing. I am using Qlikview version 11.

Comment: qvd (data) or qvw (data and layout) file you want to export?

Comment: Hi Stefan ...Its the qvw.

Comment: The qvw then is kinda easy. in the folder ,where the qvw is, create new folder named as the qvw + _prj. For example if the qvw is `MyApp.qvw` then the folder name should be `MyApp-prj`. Open `MyApp.qvw` and save it. After the save process is complete the `MyApp-prj` folder will contain the exported app structure (everything without the data). The app structure is in multiple xml files.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Will it contain reporting Data also when it is exported in XML

Comment: if by "reporting data" you mean the underlying data - no. This will export only the layout. The data can be exported very easy in csv. Not sure that there is a straight way to export it in xml. You can build the xml by yourself in the script but if you have a lot of data this process will be slow

Comment: Alright...So the Report Worksheet data (qvd) can be exported to .csv. I am new to Qlik...so can you let me know if there is a way to create HTML output too. ..Like can we open the xml into IE and the report will get designed.

Comment: Not sure you can do it so easy (if possible at all). You need to rebuild the QV Server basically which will be tremendous job.

Answer (score 0):

Qlik has a product called NPrinting which provides a comprehensive reporting solution. It allows you to use components (like charts, tables, even entire sheets) from existing QVW's (documents) and then build reports (as HTML, Excel, Word, PPT, images) and send via email or distribute into folders.

At "report run time" filters can be applied to the data model to potentially limit the data that is reported.

Might be overkill for your problem, but it could be worth a look.